# Adding elements of an array in x86-64 assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to write an x86-64 assembly program that is the function "int addarray(int n, int * array)". The first arg is the length of the array, second is a pointer to the array. It's supposed to add up the elements of the array and return. Here is the code I have so far, and I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
.text
.globl addarray
.type   addarray, @function  

addarray:
    movq    $0, %rdx
    movq    $0, %rax
while:
    cmpq    %rdx, %rdi
    jle afterw

    movq    %rdx, %rcx
    imulq   $8, %rcx
    addq    %rsi, %rcx

    addq    %rcx, %rax

    addq    $1, %rdx
    jmp while
afterw:
    ret
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Which calling convention do you use? I.e. which registers contain the arguments? My assembler is a little rusty, but doesn't `cpmq %rdx, %rdi jle afterw` immediatly jump to afterw because `$rdx` is set to 0?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not real familiar with the AT&T syntax, but it looks like your line:

```
addq %rcx, %rax
```

Is going to add the value of `rcx` to `rax`. You want to add the value that `rcx` references, that is:

```
addq (%rcx), %rax
```

At least, I think that's how it's done in AT&T syntax. In Intel syntax, it would be:

```
add rax,[rcx]
```

There are a couple of simple optimizations you can do to speed things up somewhat, but I think the above is the key to your problem.